# why is the y-axis adjusting on my ggplot2 histograms

Tags: r

the code below is for the red histogram

```
    project_completed %>% 
        select(group_slug,diff_days) %>% 
        filter(group_slug == "hr") %>% 
        ggplot(aes(diff_days))+
        geom_histogram(color = "white",bins = 30,fill = "red")
```

[image: This is an individual histogram of the red histogram "hr" catigory of the second graph]

The red histogram above is the "hr" category. This is the same red histogram in the multi-histogram below.  The maximum y-value is around 175. Now looking at the red histogram in the second plot the y-axis maximum value for the red histogram is much larger than the first histogram.

[image: histogram of different catigories]

The code is for the muli-histogram plot

```
    project_comp_times_hist <- project_completed_times %>% 
        distinct(group_slug,diff_days) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = diff_days, fill = group_slug)) +
        geom_histogram(bins = 100, color = "white")+
        geom_vline(data = project_completed_avg,
                   aes(xintercept = avg_time, color = group_slug),
                   linetype = "dashed")+

        labs(
            title = "Distribution of time spent on projects in the Group Slug Category",
            subtitle = "All Distribution are positively skewed ",
            x = "Number of Days on Project(Group Slup)"

        ) +
        theme(
            axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold")
        )
```

my question is: why? For the individual red "hr" category histogram the maximum points are around 175, and the y-axis of the multi-histogram plot is much higher. I used the "hr" category as an example, but all categories show this discrepancy between the y-axes. I would really appreciate it if anyone could explain this.

Comment: Your first plot has bins 30 and 2nd plot has bins 100 try making them equal and replot

Comment: To ensure consistent binwidth across plots you can use binwidth. For example `geom_histogram(binwidth=1)`